# With Phonegap apps, is the javascriptcode visible on Android and IOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, hide

I am creating an app and will use Phonegap to make it for both Android and iPhone.

Will the javascriptcode be unavailable since it is now installed as and app on those devices?
I have seen you may obscure it but that's just to make it harder to read, not unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the JavaScript is easily extractable. For example, in an iOS app, an .ipa package is just a zip file. If you unzip the IPA, then look in your app bundle, the `www` folder (for example) containing all of your HTML, JavaScript, etc. will be available.

You can do your best to obfuscate your JavaScript, but at the end of the day, it needs to be available for execution.